# SQL Statement with bad performance

Tags: sql, excel, vba, performance

I am trying to use SQL statements in an Excel VBA project to get the amount of table entries according to a specific SQL statement. The return value (integer) will then be stored in an array. Currently one statement takes almost 1 second to be performed. Since I have more than 10000 of those queries, I would like to improve the performance:

**My Main Sub**

```vb
Dim x As Integer: x = 0
For i = 0 To 10000
  x = RunSQLQuery(mySQLQuery)
Next
```

**The Function to Set up the SQL Connection**

```vb
Function SetSQLConnection(cn As Object) As Variant
    
        'Connect to Workbook
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
        .Open
    End With

End Function
```

**The Function to get an integer with the help of an SQL query** (The ".Execute" in this function ist the slow part)

```vb
Function RunSQLQuery(mySQLString) As Integer
    Dim rs As Object
    Set rs = sqlObject.Execute(mySQLString)
    RunSQLQuery = rs(0)
End Function
```

Comment: You would be better off using MS Access or SQLServer to store and query data. There are solutions to overcome slowness by using COM and store indexes in memory. However, no matter what you do, using Excel as a database will eventually lead you to a brick wall .

Comment: Crucially missing in this story is *what the actual query is*, *what your data looks like* and the *expected results* -- and why you're using an SQL query in the first place, instead of accessing the workbook directly.

Comment: Most likely this is not the optimal approach but as Jeroen notes we have no idea what you're actually doing with your SQL.